# Is sizeof(T) == sizeof(int)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I've been poring over the draft standard and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

If I have a standard-layout type

```
struct T {
   unsigned handle;
};
```

Then I know that `reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&t) == &t.handle` for some `T t;`

The goal is to create some `vector<T> v` and pass `&v[0]` to a C function that expects a pointer to an array of unsigned integers.

So, does the standard define `sizeof(T) == sizeof(unsigned)` and does that imply that an array of `T` would have the same layout as an array of `unsigned`?

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585033/size-of-struct-with-a-single-element) addresses a very similar topic, I'm asking about the specific case where both the data member and the class are standard layout, and the data member is a fundamental type.

I've read some paragraphs that seem to hint that *maybe* it might be true, but nothing that hits the nail on the head. For example:

§ 9.2.17

> Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if
>   they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding
>   non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible
>   types

This isn't quite what I'm looking for, I don't think.

Comment: Why not just vector::data() ?

Comment: For int it may be valid, but in general there might be trailing padding after 'handle'.

Comment: @anthony-arnold Oops, sorry. Didn't read the question carefully enough. -- You can always `static_assert` for potentially non-portable code.

Comment: [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a604c61047b97eef) a contrived counter-example.

Comment: I can't imagine how it matters if the data member is standard layout or not. That aspect is encapsulated from the padding behaviors of its container.

Comment: My guess is you're looking for a guarantee that simply doesn't exist. Structures may have padding at the end, regardless of the layout type.

Comment: @tenfour Yes, I guess so. If the answer is the same then I suppose the question should just remain closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You essentially are asking, given:

```
struct T {
    U handle;
};
```

whether it's guaranteed that `sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)`.  No, it is not.

Section 9.2/17 of the ISO C++03 standard says:

> A pointer to a POD-struct object, suitably converted using a
>   `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

Suppose you have an array of `struct T`.  The vice versa part means that the address of any of the `T::handle` members must also be a valid address of a `struct T`.  Now, suppose that these members are of type `char` and that your claim is true.  This would mean that `struct T` would be allowed to have an unaligned address, which seems rather unlikely.  The standard usually tries to not tie the hands of implementations in such a way.  For your claim to be true, the standard would have to require that `struct T` be allowed to have unaligned addresses.  And it would have to be allowed for all structures, because `struct T` could be a forward-declared, opaque type.

Furthermore, section 9.2/17 goes on to state:

> [Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a POD-struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment.]

Which, taken a different way, means that there is no guarantee that there will never be padding.

Comment: If `T::handle` is of type `char`, then `alignof(T::handle)` is `alignof(char) == 1`. So *any* alignment for `T` would result in aligned `handles` within an array of `T` - indeed, `handle` *cannot* be unaligned.

Comment: @jamesdlin I see you point, and it's a bummer. I was hoping for a some sort of caveat around standard layout/integers/fundamental alignment etc. Ah well. I have added some compile time checking that `sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)` and doing the call the long way if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

I am used to Borland environments and for them:

T is a struct in your case so sizeof(T) is size of struct

- that depends on **#pragma pack** and **align** setting of your compiler
- so sometimes it can be greater than sizeof(unsigned) !!!

for the same reason if you have 4Byte struct (uint32) and 16Byte allign

- struct T { uint32 u; };
- then T a[100] is not the same as uint32 a[100];
- because T is uint32 + 12 Byte empty space !!!

Answer (score 3):

RETRACTION: The argument is erroneous. The proof of Lemma 2 relies on a hidden premise that the alignment of an aggregate type is determined strictly by the alignments of its member types. As [Dyp points out in the commentary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499120/is-sizeoft-sizeofint/21515546?noredirect=1#comment32484754_21515546), that premise is not supported by the standard. It is therefore admissible for `struct { Foo f }` to have a more strict alignment requirement that `Foo`.

---

I'll play devil's advocate here, since no one else seems to be willing. I will argue that standard C++ ([I'll refer to N3797 herein](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) guarantees that `sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)` when `T` is a standard layout class (9/7) with default alignment having a single default-aligned non-static data member `U`, e.g,

```
struct T { // or class, or union
  U u;
};
```

It's well-established that:

- `sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U)`
- `offsetof(T, u) == 0` (9.2/19)
- `U` must be a standard layout type for `T` to be a standard layout class
- `u` has a representation consisting of exactly `sizeof(U)` contiguous bytes of memory (1.8/5)

Together these facts imply that the first `sizeof(U)` bytes of the representation of `T` are occupied by the representation of `u`. If `sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)`, the excess bytes must then be *tail padding*: unused padding bytes inserted after the representation of `u` in `T`.

The argument is, in short:

- The standard details the circumstances in which an implementation may add padding to a standard-layout class,
- None of those cirumstances applies in this particular instance, and hence
- A conforming implementation may not add padding.

---

#### Potential Sources of Padding

Under what circumstances does the standard allow an implementation to add such padding to the representation of a standard layout class? When it's necessary for alignment: per 3.11/1, "An *alignment* is an implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated." There are two mentions of adding padding, both for alignment reasons:

- 5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]/2 states "When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type. When applied
  to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in an array. The size of a most derived class shall be greater than zero (1.8). The result of applying `sizeof` to a base class subobject is the size of the base class type.<sup>77</sup> When applied to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of *n* elements is *n* times the size of an element."
- 9.2 Class members [class.mem]/13 states "Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1)."
- (Notably the C++ standard does *not* contain a blanket statement allowing implementations to insert padding in structures as in the C standards, e.g., N1570 (C11-ish) §6.7.2.1/15 "There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning." and /17 "There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.")

Clearly the text of 9.2 doesn't apply to our problem, since (a) `T` has only one member and thus no "adjacent members", and (b) `T` is standard layout and hence has no virtual functions or virtual base classes (per 9/7). Demonstrating that 5.3.3/2 doesn't allow padding in our problem is more challenging.

---

#### Some Prerequisites

*Lemma 1:* **For any type `W` with default alignment, `alignof(W)` divides `sizeof(W)`:** By 5.3.3/2, the size of an array of *n* elements of type `W` is exactly *n* times `sizeof(W)` (i.e., there is no "external" padding between array elements). The addresses of consecutive array elements are then `sizeof(W)` bytes apart. By the definition of alignment, it must then be that `alignof(W)` divides `sizeof(W)`.

*Lemma 2:* **The alignment `alignof(W)` of a default-aligned standard layout class `W` with only default-aligned data members is the least common multiple `LCM(W)` of the alignments of the data members (or 1 if there are none):** Given an address at which an object of `W` can be allocated, the address `LCM(W)` bytes away must also be appropriately aligned: the difference between the addresses of member subobjects would also be `LCM(W)` bytes, and the alignment of each such member subobject divides `LCM(W)`. Per the definition of alignment in 3.11/1, we have that `alignof(W)` divides `LCM(W)`. Any whole number of bytes `n < LCM(W)` must not be divisible by the alignment of some member `v` of `W`, so an address that is only `n` bytes away from an address at which an object of `W` can be allocated is consequently *not* appropriately aligned for an object of `W`, i.e., `alignof(W) >= LCM(W)`. Given that `alignof(W)` divides `LCM(W)` and `alignof(W) >= LCM(W)`, we have `alignof(W) == LCM(W)`.

---

#### Conclusion

Application of this lemma to the original problem has the immediate consequence that `alignof(T) == alignof(U)`. So how much padding might be "required for placing objects of that type in an array"? *None*. Since `alignof(T) == alignof(U)` by the second lemma, and `alignof(U)` divides `sizeof(U)` by the first, it must be that `alignof(T)` divides `sizeof(U)` so zero bytes of padding are required to place objects of type `T` in an array.

Since all possible sources of padding bytes have been eliminated, an implementation may not add padding to `T` and we have `sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)` as required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how 3.11/1 requires that `alignof(W)` *divides* `LCM(W)`? I.e. why doesn't it allow overalignment (not in the sense of extended alignment, but e.g. `alignof(W) == 2*LCM(W)`)?

Comment: 3.11/1 says an alignment is "...the number of bytes between **successive** addresses at which a given object can be allocated." If `foo` is acceptable, then the next *successive* address that results in properly aligned members is `foo + LCM(W)`. `2 * LCM(W)` would obviously be suitably aligned, but not successive.

Comment: I think that would require interpreting the *"can be allocated"* as a restriction imposed upon the implementation. If you'd interpret that as a restriction imposed upon the program, `2*LCM(W)` might be possible (i.e. the implementation requires the program to "over-align" objects of that composed type, even though the hardware could support a weaker alignment).

Comment: @dyp Ok, I think I get your point now. I'm assuming that the alignment of an aggregate type is dictated only by the alignment requirements of its members. You suggest that an implementation may have a *more* strict requirement for the aggregate than is necessary to align the members.

Comment: @dyp After checking, I concur that the standard admits that  interpretation. Thank you for the review and pointing out the hidden premise.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for a well thought out answer. I'm sorry that it turned out to be wrong; both for your sake and for my own efforts that led me to ask the question in the first place.