# Common initial sequence and alignment

Tags: c++, c++11, unions, memory-alignment, standard-layout

While thinking of a counter-example for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21499120/420683), I came up with:

```
struct A
{
    alignas(2) char byte;
};
```

But if that's legal and standard-layout, is it layout-compatible to this `struct B`?

```
struct B
{
    char byte;
};
```

Furthermore, if we have

```
struct A
{
    alignas(2) char x;
    alignas(4) char y;
};
// possible alignment, - is padding
// 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
//  x  -  -  -  y  -  -  -  x  -  -  -  y  -  -  -

struct B
{
    char x;
    char y;
}; // no padding required

union U
{
    A a;
    B b;
} u;
```

Is there a common initial sequence for `A` and `B`? If so, does it include `A::y` & `B::y`? I.e., may we write the following w/o invoking UB?

```
u.a.y = 42;
std::cout << u.b.y;
```

(answers for C++1y / "fixed C++11" also welcome)

---

- See [basic.align] for alignment and [dcl.align] for the alignment-specifier.
- [basic.types]/11 says for fundamental types "If two types `T1` and `T2` are the same type, then `T1` and `T2` are layout-compatible types." (an underlying question is whether `A::byte` and `B::byte` have layout-compatible types)
- [class.mem]/16 "Two standard-layout struct types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types."
- [class.mem]/18 "Two standard-layout structs share a common initial
  sequence if corresponding members have layout-compatible types and either neither member is a bit-field or
  both are bit-fields with the same width for a sequence of one or more initial members."
- [class.mem]/18 "If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence,
  and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted
  to inspect the common initial part of any of them."

Of course, on a language-lawyer level, another question is what it means that the inspection of the common initial sequence is "permitted". I guess some other paragraph might make the above `u.b.x` undefined behaviour (reading from an uninitialized object).

Comment: I don't think this is a good example. The structure with an `int` and a `char` has `int` alignment. That `alignas(2)` attribute for `char byte` as a first element is a no-op because that first element already has `alignas(int)` alignment. A possibly better example: `struct A {int x; alignas(double) char byte;};`

Comment: @DavidHammen Ouch, true, I've meant to add padding *after* the byte. Fixing..

Comment: @DavidHammen I hope the example is better now.

Comment: There is no padding in front of x (regarding ASCII-art where x is at 02)

Comment: @DieterLücking Hmm no that would be illegal. There can be no padding at the beginning of a standard-layout struct. But the Standard doesn't allow the "odd" alignment I had in mind either, so I've removed that line. The remaining one is the alignment g++ and clang++ seem to be using.

Comment: Hmm. I thought had an answer, but then I thought some more. The more I look at the standard there appears to be a misalignment problem. Is `alignas` a part of the *type-id* or not? In some places it appears that this is the case, in others, it appears that this definitely is not the case.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yeah.. I started wondering about the whole issue when I tried [`static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(A::byte), char>::value, "!");`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88465649d58ba91b) which then lead to this question.

Comment: Side note: If a class using `alignas` on its members is not intended to be standard-layout, then `sizeof(A)` could be four, with the second member at offset 0, and the first at offset 2. Somewhat more relevant note: the current wording of "standard-layout" that already makes the literal requirements unimplementable for other reasons. [Details here.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1672) I looked for open issues regarding alignment too, but found nothing of interest.

Comment: Nasty.  But yeah, looks like the Standard doesn't address this well enough.  The "obvious" intent is to define layout-compatible structs and common initial sequences as involving the same base classes with same alignments and the same member types with same alignments.

Comment: @Tshepang According to the tag wiki, [union] is for SQL UNION, whereas [unions] is for C, C++ etc. `union`s.

Comment: That feels forced @dyp. We need better tags, maybe [tag:c-union].

Comment: @Tshepang I agree. Maybe [union] should be replaced by [SQL-UNION] and [unions] by [c-union]. Maybe there's been some discussion on meta? Otherwise, it might be worth a new question there. Edit: just upvoted your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

I may not speak for C++11 standard, but I am a firmware/microchip programmer and have had to use such features that exist for a long time (pragma pack, alignment attributes).

Using `alignas` cannot be considered "standard layout", thus all the implications are useless. Standard layout means one fixed alignment distribution (per architecture - usually all is `align(min(sizeof,4))` or some may be `align(8)`). The standard probably wants to say what is obvious: without using special features (`align`,`pack`) structures are compatible on the same architecture if they appear to be the same (same types in same order). Otherwise, they may or may not be compatible - depending on architecture (may be compatible on one architecture but different on another).

Consider this struct:

```
struct foo{ char b; short h; double d; int i; };
```

On one architecture (e.g. x86 32bit) it is what it seems to be, but on Itanium or ARM it actually looks like this:

```
struct foo{char b, **_hidden_b**; short h; **int _maybe_hidden_h**; double d; int i;}
```

Notice `_maybe_hidden_h` - it can be omitted in older AEABI (align to max 4) or there for 64bit/8B alignment.

x86 Standard Layout (pack(1)):

```
alignas(1) char b; alignas(1) short h; alignas(1) double d; alignas(1) int i;
```

32bit Alignment Standard Layout (pack(4) - ARM architecture, older version - EABI)

```
alignas(1) char b; alignas(2) short h; **alignas(4) double d**; alignas(4) int i;
```

64bit Alignment Standard Layout (pack(8) - Itanium and newer ARM/AEABI)

```
alignas(1) char b; alignas(2) short h; **alignas(8) double d**; alignas(4) int i;
```

**To your example:

`offsetof(A,y) = 4` while `offsetof(B,y) = 2` and the union does not change that (thus `&u.a.y != u.b.y`)**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a hole in the standard. The responsible thing would be to file a [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html).

Several things, though:

- Your first example doesn't really demonstrate a problem. Adding a `short` after the `char` would also have the effect of aligning the `char` to a 2-byte boundary, without changing the common subsequence.
- `alignas` is not C++-only; it was added simultaneously to [C11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/align/alignas). Since the standard-layout property is a cross-language compatibility facility, it is probably preferable to require corresponding alignment specifiers to match than to disqualify a class with a nonstatic member alignment-specifier.
- There would be no problem if the member alignment specifiers appertained to the types of the members. Other problems may result from the lack of adjustment to types, for example a function parameter `ret fn( alignas(4) char )` may need to be mangled for the ABI to process it correctly, but the language might not provide for such adjustment.

Comment: Oops, of course. The first example was the more language-lawyery formulation of the problem that manifests in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

> (an underlying question is whether A::byte and B::byte have layout-compatible types)

Yes. This is the essential part. The `alignas`-attribute appertains to the **entity declared**, not the type. Can be easily tested by `std::is_same` and `decltype`.

> I.e., may we write the following w/o invoking UB?

This is therefore not UB, the relevant paragraphes have been quoted by you.

EDIT: Pardon me, this can of course result in UB because the padding between members is not (or implementation-) defined (§9.2/13)! I accidently misread the example, because i thought it accessed x instead of y, because with x it actually always works - whereas with y it theoretically doesn't have to (though it practically always will).

Comment: How is that implemented, then? `u.a.y = 42;` writes to the second byte of the structure; if `u.b.y` shall contain the same value one would need either to track the active member of the union or also write to the fifth byte of the structure in `u.a.y = 42;`, right?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute - i just realized you did a completely different example than i thought. You use y instead of x. Well now that is NOT defined, since there can be any padding between members! I'll add that to the post as well :)

Comment: Yes, the padding between members is implementation-defined. But if there's a common initial sequence, you might access all those members of this sequence (not just the first). The question now is: What is the common initial sequence for those two structs? Does it include the second member? I'd say *no*, but where is this specified?

Comment: You gave the necessary quote yourself: If the members have layout-compatible types. And since the types are the same, you may modify them. Alignment is automatically taken from the strictest requirement from all the union members. Still i reckon this being weird, since this would make assumptions over the compability of structs...

Comment: So you mean that `u.a.y` will also have an alignment of 4 since `u.a` in the same union as `u.b`? Then, other assignments like `A x; x = u.a;` had to be changed. I'm not yet convinced how this all is intended to fits together.

Comment: Yes, it will have the same alignment. Otherwise this rule couldn't apply. *Or* the standard does somehow not specify precisely enough, how layout-compability is related to alignment of the objects declared with `alignas`.

Comment: I suspect the latter is the case ;) That's why I keep asking.. Well maybe I should ask this on the isocpp mailing list to see whether it's considered a defect or not.