# Fields with the same name across different anonymous structures inside on union

Tags: c++

Is it legal to have fields with the same name across different anonymous structures inside one `union`?

```
union Foo
{
    struct
    {
        int bar;
    };

    struct
    {
        int bar;
    };
};
```

MSVC does in fact allow this while GCC doesn't.

Comment: Your use-case for doing this is - what?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth It was actually made by an accident as the real example is much bigger and more complex than the one I've provided here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "anonymous structs" standard? And, really, what \*are\* they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous union and struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542390/anonymous-union-and-struct)

Comment: Disable language extensions of `cl` (`/Za`) and get: `error C2467: illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'` and `error C2658: 'Foo::bar': redefinition in anonymous struct/union`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is not valid, simply because C++ has no anonymous structures.

With `-pedantic-errors`, GCC refuses to compile it with `error: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-Wpedantic]`.

Comment: I've just updated my question, please take a look at the new version.

Comment: @FrozenHeart I'd say it warrants a separate question, probably tagged `language-lawyer`. But since both GCC and Clang reject the new snippet as well, I smell MSVC bug.